# Find the limit of the sequence, complex analysis

Tags: complex-analysis

I am fairly new to complex analysis and I am having a hard time understanding why the limit does not exist for the following sequence. $z_n = n + i/n$.

Comment: Do you have an initial condition?

Comment: Note $|z_n| > n$

Comment: @Peter Foreman, there are no initial conditions. The problem asks if the limit exists, then find it. If it does not, then explain why

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** a sequence $\{z_n=x_n+iy_n\}_{n=1}^\infty\subseteq\mathbb{C}$ converges to a number $z=x+iy$ if and only if $x_n\to x$ and $y_n\to y$. So if you know how to deal with sequences of real numbers then it should be easy.

Comment: Does this mean that the imaginary part is undefined and hence the limit does not exist?

Comment: The imaginary part is fine. The problem in your sequence is the real part. The sequence of real parts is $x_n=n$ and it doesn't converge to any real number.

Comment: Ohh, my bad. Did not even notice that properly. Thank you!